# The Problem with redirecting to specific page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

See the problem commented below,its not redirecting to specific page named "login". I want to redirect it to the login page but after trying to login its not redirecting to login page.I used res.redirect("/login"),but instead redirecting to login page it remains on home page. I am not getting the solution for this problem.

```
const app = express();
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static("images"));
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/UserDB",{useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true});
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  usernameo:{
    type:String
  },
  new_password:{
    type:String
  },
  con_password:{
      type:String
    }
});
const User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  var path = require('path');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+"/project.html"));
});
app.get("/login",function(req,res){
  var path = require('path');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+"/loggedin.html"));
});
app.post("/",function(req,res){
//for signup
const name =req.body.usernameo;
const new_passwordo=req.body.new_password;
const con_passwordo=req.body.con_password;
if(new_passwordo===con_passwordo){
    const user = new User({
      usernameo:name,
      new_password:new_passwordo,
      con_password:con_passwordo
      });
      user.save();
      res.redirect("/");}
  else{
res.json({
  message:"Password did not matched"
});}
//for login
const uname = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  User.findOne({usernameo: uname}, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err) {console.log(err);}
      else{
        if(foundUser){if(foundUser.con_password === password) {
            console.log("Logged In");
            res.redirect("/login");  //PROBLEM-- it is not redirecting
          }
         else{console.log("Invalid username or password");}
        }
      }
    });
});
app.listen(3000,function()
{
  console.log("Server running successfully"); 
});
javascript node.js mongodb
```

Comment: Are u able to `console.log('Logged In')`?

Comment: no but if I put everything in one app.post("/",...) instead in seperate app.post() but after printing -Logged In ,it showing an error like-cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: @AngelinaTsuboi its not working ,may be because I am working on localhost

Comment: @ShivamSood I edited a question by putting everything in one app.post but after consoling Logged In it showing error -cannot set headers after they are sent to the client ,without  redirecting

Comment: @AngelinaTsuboi,also showing window is not defined

Comment: The "cannot set headers after they've been sent" error is telling you you're hitting more than one redirect in your function, probably `res.redirect("/")` after `if (new_passwordo === con_passwordo)` and then `res.redirect("/login")` after `(foundUser.con_password === password)`. The response header is sent on the first redirect, and cannot be sent again, so you need to sort out your logic so it only sends one redirect when you have an existing user who's passwords match.

Comment: @dikuw is there any other alternative that I can use to redirect to login?I am not getting its alternative

Comment: Typically a new user is not added from the same form as the login - there's a separate registration form for new users. But can't you just remove the `res.redirect("/")` under `(new_passwordo===con_passwordo)`? I'm not sure why you want to redirect the user here.

Comment: You've got some other inefficiencies/errors in your code which you might not want to hear about now: 1) you're storing the password twice in the userSchema - I can't see a logical reason for that. Also, I hope you have a plan for encrypting passwords for any production apps. On your `.post("/")` route you're going to need to `await` adding the new user if you want to then login with that user. 3) in the same route, you're assigning redundant variables to `req.body.username` and `req.body.password`. You can reuse the variables you first created.